# What's the difference between "balance laws" and "conservation laws"?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

What's the difference between "balance laws" and "conservation laws" ?
Can someone give me some examples?

Answer (score 5):

In the partial differential equations literature, the terms *conservation law* and *balance law* refer to particular types of first-order PDEs in space and time. Such equations are very common in physics since they express the conservation of a quantity over time (cf. the [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) and the [continuity equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation)). The use presented hereinafter is quite common.

Systems of *conservation laws* are equations of the form
$$
\partial_t\boldsymbol{u} + \sum_{k=1}^d \partial_{x_k} \boldsymbol{f}_k(\boldsymbol{u}) = \boldsymbol{0}\, ,
$$
where $\boldsymbol{u} \in \Bbb R^p$ is the vector of conserved variables, $\boldsymbol{f}_k \in \Bbb R^p$ is the flux along the $k$th spatial direction, and $d$ denotes the spatial dimension. A single conservation law corresponds to the case $p=1$. Typical examples are the linear advection equation $u_t + u_x = 0$ and the inviscid Burgers equation $u_t + uu_x = 0$.

Systems of *balance laws* are systems of conservation laws with some additional terms, such as the relaxation term $\boldsymbol{r}(\boldsymbol{u})$ in
$$
\partial_t\boldsymbol{u} + \sum_{k=1}^d \partial_{x_k} \boldsymbol{f}_k(\boldsymbol{u}) = \boldsymbol{r}(\boldsymbol{u})\, .
$$
A typical example of a single such balance law is the Burgers equation with relaxation $u_t + uu_x = -u$.

**Remark.** Many authors use sometimes the term *balance law* for the particular case of conservation laws. In practice, the vocabulary may vary from one author to another, so it is hard to make a clear semantic distinction between conservation laws and balance laws.

Answer (score 2):

Balance laws refer to quantities that balance each other, like forces.

Conservation laws refer to quantities that are conserved in a closed system, like energy and momentum.

Comment: @Darry If this answers your question, you should accept it (and answers to all your other questions too)

Answer (score 1):

Consider a continuum, say a fluid, in a domain $\Omega$. Let $V$ be a subset of $\Omega$. It is a portion of the continuum for which we are measuring some quantity, say $G$. Then the rate of change of $G$ in $V$ can be written as
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}\int GdV = -\int G_1\vec{v}\cdot\hat{n}dS + \int G_2dV + \int G_3 dV,
\end{equation}
where $G_1\vec{v}$ is the flux of $G$ through the boundary $\partial V$ of $V$, $G_2$ is the supply of $G$ from outside of $V$ and $G_3$ is the source or sink of $G$ within $V$. A balance law becomes a conservation law when $G_3 = 0$.

Refer to 'Stability Criteria for Fluid Flows' by Georgescu and Palese for examples of balance laws that are *not* conservation laws.